# Plane constant definition in three.js

Tags: three.js

The documentation for the [Plane constructor](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Plane) says that `constant` is *the signed distance from the origin to the plane*. However, if I construct a simple "floor" below the XZ plane like this:

```
var plane = new THREE.Plane();
plane.setFromCoplanarPoints(
  new THREE.Vector3(0, -10, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(0, -10, 1),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, -10, 0)
);

console.log(plane);
```

I get the following output:

```
Plane {normal: Vector3, constant: 10, constructor: Object}
normal: Vector3
x: 0
y: 1
z: 0
<constructor>: "Vector3"
constant: 10
<constructor>: "Plane"
```

My question: why is **constant** +10 and not -10? The Y-axis points up, the floor normal points up, so movement from the origin to a plane at Y = -10 should be negative shouldn't it?

Functions like `Plane.distanceToPoint` give the correct answer so I suspect I'm not reading the documentation correctly.

[CodePen Sample](https://codesandbox.io/embed/threejs-n6f71)

Comment: Origin is in the positive [half-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_(geometry)) of the plane at 10 times of its normal. Why is it wrong?

Comment: This question was already discussed at github, see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10957. `three.js` implements `THREE.Plane` according to the Hessian Normal Form (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HessianNormalForm.html).

Comment: It's signed (if you make 10 instead of -10, you get the constant -10) it's just in reverse. It's just a convention, made to confuse you :)